# Swift: How store push notification when app is running?

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

This is my `didReceiveRemoteNotification` method to handle push notifications when they are receive din my iOS app:

```
func showNotificationDetails(userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject], application:UIApplication) {
    print("showNotificationDetails")
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let notificationController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("DynamicEventsViewController") as! DynamicEventsViewController
    notificationController.isLoadedFromNotification = true
    notificationController.eventTitle = userInfo["aps"]!["alert"] as! String
    notificationController.eventDescription = userInfo["aps"]!["message"] as! String
    notificationController.isLoadedFromNotification = true

    if let tabBarController = self.window?.rootViewController {
        tabBarController.presentViewController(notificationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber -= 1
    //application.cancelAllLocalNotifications()

}


func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {

    let state:UIApplicationState = application.applicationState
    if (state == UIApplicationState.Inactive || state == UIApplicationState.Background) {
        self.showNotificationDetails(userInfo, application: application)
    }
}
```

The problem is that if the application is running and a notification arrives, then it is not stored and it is deleted so that the user cannot see it later. How shall I proceeed in the correct way to keep notification until the user reads it?

Comment: you can show alert with notification message when the app is foreground

Comment: It is exactly what I had done but my boss does not want me to do that because he says it is not correct!

Comment: just store notification data and you can use local notification. when the app goes in background check if any stored notification available then show local notification

Comment: Would you please write some code example? Where should I store it and how?

Comment: you can store it in NSUserdefault

Answer (score 0):

First, do not store this in NSUserDefaults like Divyesh suggested.  That's obviously not what the class is for based on the name and any quick read of the documentation.

Second, your boss is wrong, and you need to be able to explain that to him.   The documentation on push notifications pretty clearly tells what happens in each state.  If the app is in the foreground, and a notification comes in, and your flags say the user wants alerts, then you ARE supposed to show the alert.

Finally, if you really want to store them, then you'll need to use Core Data or a plist or something like that.  Remember though that notifications aren't supposed to hold real data, they just give you some type of flag that you then take action based on.

Comment: You are completely right but I am afraid I cannot do anything else with him. The solution I have found is that notifications arrived when app is active are stored in a global array. Then, as soon as the app enters in background state (from any view controller) those notification are scheduled as local notification so that the user can see the banner alert. Anyway, there are apps like Whatsapp or iMessage which show a banner alert even if the app is running when a new message arrive. How can they do it? Do they use a 3-rd part framework?